# Select multiple results from sub query into single row (as array datatype)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to solve a small problem with a SQL query in an oracle database. Let's assume I have these tables:

One table that holds information about cars:

```
tblCars
ID    Model    Color
--------------------
1     Volvo    Red
2     BMW      Blue
3     BMW      Green
```

And another one containing information about drivers:

```
tblDrivers
ID    fID_tblCars    Name
---------------------------
1     1              George
2     1              Mike
3     2              Jason
4     2              Paul
5     2              William
6     3              Steve
```

Now, let's pretend that to find out the popularity of the cars, I want to create reports that contain the data about the cars **and** the people that are driving them (which seems a very reasonable thing one would accomplish with a database).

This "ReportObject" would have a string for the model, a string for the color and an array (or a list) of strings for the drivers.

Currently, I do this with two queries, in the first I select the cars

```
SELECT ID, Model, Color FROM tblCars
```

and create a report object for each result.

Then, I would take each result and get the drivers for each specific car

```
SELECT Name FROM tblDrivers WHERE fID_tblCars = ResultObject.ID
```

Basically, step one gives me a resulting data set that looks like this:

```
Result
------------------------------------------
ColumnID        ColumnModel    ColumnColor
Type Integer    Type String    Type String
```

and now, if I will have more cars in the future, I will have to make a lot of additional queries, one for each row in the resulting table.

When I try this:

```
SELECT Model, Color, (SELECT Name FROM tblDrivers WHERE tblDrivers.fID_tblCars = tblCars.ID) as Name FROM tblCars
```

I get some error message telling me that one result in the row contains multiple elements (which is what I want!).

I want the result to look like this:

```
Result
--------------------------------------------------------
ColumnID        ColumnModel    ColumnColor    ColumnName
Type Integer    Type String    Type String    Type Array
```

So when I build my report object, I could do something like this:

```
foreach (var Row in Results)
{
    ReportObject.Model = Row.Model;
    ReportObject.Color = Row.Color;
    foreach (string Driver in Row.Name)
    {
        ReportObject.Drivers.Add(Driver);
    }
}
```

Am I completely missing my basics here or do I **have** to split this up in multiple queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in Oracle. In the SQL Fiddle example I couldn't get the IDENTITY or the PRIMARY KEYS to work when creating the table (never used Oracle SQL before)

```
SELECT  c.id, 
    c.model, 
    c.color,
    LISTAGG(d.name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY d.name) AS "Drivers"
FROM tblCars c
JOIN tblDrivers d
ON c.id = d.fID_TblCars
GROUP BY c.id,
    c.model,
    c.color
ORDER BY c.Id
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1733/1/0)

Comment: This looks promising, but it doesn't work on an Oracle database. Is there any general SQL way to solve this?

Comment: My bad, I missed the oracle tab. You could try the LISTAGG function in replace of the SQL STUFF/FOR XML functions. http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php

Comment: Should be okay now. Try it out and let me know.